# Optimal exponent in Dirichlet’s theorem on diophantine approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\vec x = (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$.
Dirichlet’s theorem guarantees that for each $N$, there exists $(n_0,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^{k+1} \setminus \{\vec 0\}$ with $\max(|n_1|,|n_2|,\dots,|n_k|) \leq N$ and
$$ |n_0+ n_1x_1 + n_2 x_2 + \dots + n_k x_k| < N^{-k}.$$
It is [known](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa16/aa1647.pdf) that for almost all $\vec x$ this cannot be improved, in the sense that it's not possible to replace the bounds $N$ and $N^{-k}$ with $(1-\varepsilon)N$ and $(1-\varepsilon)N^{-k}$ respectively, for a positive constant $\varepsilon > 0$. Conversely, the "trivial" example where $\vec x$ satisfies an affine relation over $\mathbb{Q}$ shows that there certainly are *some* $\vec x$ for which the above can be improved in a rather spectacular manner.

I'm curious if, except for the trivial case mentioned above, the exponent $k$ in Dirichlet’s theorem is optimal. More precisely, I wonder if the following is true:

*Let $\vec x = (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Suppose that for each sufficiently large $N$ there exists $(n_0,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^{k+1} \setminus \{\vec 0\}$ with $\max(|n_1|,|n_2|,\dots,|n_k|) \leq N$ and
$$ |n_0+ n_1x_1 + n_2 x_2 + \dots + n_k x_k| < N^{-k-\varepsilon}.$$
Then $1,x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$.*

---

As a rationale, let's consider the case $k = 1$. In this case, we have a single real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for each $N$ there exist $n < N$ such that $\Vert n x \Vert < N^{-1-\varepsilon}$, and we claim that $x$ needs to be rational. (Here $\Vert t \Vert$ denotes the distance of $t$ from $\mathbb{Z}$.) Suppose conversely that $x$ is irrational, and let $x = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\dots]$ be the continued fraction expansion of $x$, and let $p_1/q_1,p_2/q_2,\dots$ be the convergents. Then, setting $N = q_{i+1} - 1$ and recalling the convergents are the best rational approximations of the second kind, we see that $\Vert q_i x \Vert < q_{i+1}^{-1-\varepsilon}$. On the other hand, we have the estimate $(q_{i+1}+ q_i)^{-1} < \Vert q_i x \Vert < q_{i+1}^{-1}$. This would imply that $(q_{i+1}+ q_i)^{-1} < q_{i+1}^{-1-\varepsilon}$, which is impossible for sufficiently large $i$.

The basic intuition, as far as I can tell, is that if for a specific threshold $N_0$ we have an approximation that is much better than expected, then we can use it to describe all reasonable approximations for a larger threshold $N_1$ and none of those approximations is particularly good (above, $N_0 = q_i$ and $N_1 = q_{i+1}-1$). I'm not sure how (and if) this idea works for $k \geq 2$, and I suspect the above conjecture is either well-known or demonstrably false.

Comment: Khinchine proved in 1935 that for any positive-valued function $f$ there are irrational $\alpha$, and $\beta$ such that $1,\alpha,\beta$ are limearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $|n_0+n_1\alpha+n_2\beta|<f(N)$ has a solution with $|n_i|\leq N$, $i=0,1,2$ for any positive integer $N$. You can find it in Cassels, "An Introduction to Diophantine Approximation", Ch. V, Theorem XIV

Comment: @OlegEroshkin: Thank you! This solves the problem completely.